# Are probability density functions nondecreasing?

Tags: probability

I know cumulative density functions are nondecreasing by definition, and I know that the PDF is just the derivative of the CDF, but are probability density functions also nondecreasing?

Comment: Typo in your question? The last sentence seems confusing.

Answer (score 2):

No, check the gaussian density: [graph.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg)

Comment: In short: A CDF is non-decreasing, but the *rate* of this increase *may* decrease .

Answer (score 0):

A probability density function $p(x)$ is positive by definition. The cumulative distribution function is the integral (area under curve) of the probability density function. As the integrand is positive the integral will be monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 0):

No. If probability density functions were non-decreasing, it would imply that larger values are always at least as likely as smaller values, which isn't the case. For example, if you wanted a probability density of human height, a non-decreasing function would require that the likelihood of seeing someone between 5 and 6 feet tall would be no bigger than the likelihood of seeing someone between 8 and 9 feet tall, or between 99 and 100 feet tall, which clearly makes no sense.

A non-decreasing PDF would extend infinitely to the right and likely have infinite area underneath it, but PDFs must have area 1 under the curve. Every PDF in fact must *not be* non-decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two CDF's

[image]

Both are non decreasing (even increasing) but

1. the blue one is convex, that means that its second derivatives is always  $>0$. This means that the derivative of the CDF (the pdf) has a first derivative always positive...the pdf is itself always increasing.
2. On the countary, the red CDF is convex and concave (when 1<x<2). This means that its second derivative is less than zero...which means that the first derivative of the CDF's derivative (the pdf) is less than zero...in other words in this interval the pdf is decreasing

When X>2 both CDF=1 constant, meaning that when $x\geq 2$ both pdf's are zero